# Why do we study black hole quasi-normal modes for different fields?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, normal-modes

In [Zhidenko's paper on quasi-normal modes of a Schwarzschild de Sitter black hole](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0307012v5), he considers the damped oscillations in the background space-time (quasi-normal modes) for fields of different spin (e.g. scalar, Dirac, electromagnetic, gravitational, etc.).

What physical value is there in studying quasi-normal modes modelled as different oscillating fields?